# Start and end dates to carto torque

Tags: carto, heat-map, torque

Is there a way to have a start and end date in a Carto timeline (instead of the usual start OR end date?

I don't have any programming experience.

Comment: The start and end date depends on your data. Torque would start with the first date and would end with the last. Could you give us more info about what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks. Each point on my map has an individual start and end date, and I would like to have torque to recognize those--not only the first and last dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Torque](https://carto.com/torque/) works aggregating your data in bins according to a specific date/timestamp column. However, you have two. So, in order to get the animated map you are looking for, you have to restructure your table.

I suggest duplicating (unnesting) each row in two so you will have the same point/register twice with two different dates (start and end) but same id (category). Now you will be able to make a Torque Category map.